# Magento set AS in getCollection()

Tags: magento, collections

I've got this function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_invoice.order_id',array('increment_id'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

The increment_id already exists, so when I manually run the script I get 2 columns with the name: "increment_id" so I would like to name the increment_id from the second $collection.

I've tried: `$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_invoice.order_id',array('increment_id AS increment_id2'));` but this doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (has not tested yet)

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    array("sfi"=>'sales_flat_invoice'), 
    'main_table.entity_id = sfi.order_id',
    'sfi.increment_id AS increment_id2');
```

From http://prattski.com/2010/10/21/magento-collection-join-does-not-allow-table-aliases/